# Apache: redirect all files in specific folder and subfolders to another url

Tags: apache, redirect

How can I redirect all requests from a subfolder (and all subfolders underneath) to a specific external URL?

```
www.example.com/oldfolder/ 
www.example.com/oldfolder/abc/
www.example.com/oldfolder/xyz/whatever/
```

should be redirected to one new URL: [www.otherdomain.com/new/](http://www.otherdomain.com/new/)
(Without keeping the rest of the path)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/oldfolder/?(.*) https://www.otherdomain.com/new/
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for an actual answer, here's a definitive one:

I want to redirect paths that match `/fr[/**]` to `/[**]`.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/fr/?(.*)$ /$1
```

The code above seems to work, but there's one issue: the regex is too permissive.

Indeed, with such a directive `/friend` would be redirected to `/iend` which is not what we want.

Thus, what we need is to split the rewrite into 2 directives:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/fr/(.*)$ /$1
Redirect 301 /fr /
```

The first one matches any "child" route, whilst the second one only takes care of the "root".